# How to automatically adjust text size for phone in html?

Tags: html, css

please help me out!

I tried this code `<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" charset="UTF-8">"` and it worked for everything such as background, text,...

However, when I put the `<div>` tag with `class` inside the body in order to style in in css, the content stopped adjusting in phones.

So how can I fix that?

Comment: Read this: https://madebymike.com.au/writing/precise-control-responsive-typography/

Comment: you need to use media query in css for phone, tablet and other stuff

Comment: `font-size: 1vw;` or `font-size: 1vh;`

Comment: @Araz thank you. I made it.